Density-density correlator at quasi-classical approach
Consider quasiclassical 1D motion in some potential $U$. Interresting property is following correlator:
\begin{equation}
K_E(\Delta t,x'|x) = \int \frac{d \omega}{2\pi} G^R_{E+\omega/2}(x'|x) G^A_{E-\omega/2}(x'|x) e^{-i \omega \Delta t}
\end{equation}
I want to calculate this correlator in limit $E \Delta t \gg \hbar$.
In quassiclassical limit correlator is
\begin{equation}
 K(\Delta t,x'|x) \approx m^2  \int (d \omega) 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{p_{E + \frac{\omega}{2}}(x)p_{E + \frac{\omega}{2}}(x')p_{E - \frac{\omega}{2}}(x)p_{E - \frac{\omega}{2}}(x')}}  \exp(- i \omega \Delta t + i \int_x^{x'} \big[p_{E + \frac{\omega}{2}}(x_1) - p_{E - \frac{\omega}{2}}(x_1) \big] dx_1  )
\end{equation}
$p_E(x) = \sqrt{2 m (E- U(x)) }$. I now can expand expressions for small $\omega$. Thus, i have
\begin{equation}
K(\Delta t,x'|x) \approx \frac{m^2}{p_E(x)p_{E'}(x')}\int (d \omega) \exp(i \omega (-\Delta t + \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}) ) \sim \delta(T_E(x'|x) - \Delta t)
\end{equation}
Answer is pretty logical: Correlator takes significant value, when time of motion $\Delta t$ equal to  $T_E(x'|x)$, which is time needed classical particle to travel from $x$ to $x'$ in potential $U$. My problem is following
Actually, right answer is some function $F$, which is big, when $\Delta t = T_E$ and have width $\delta T$. I tried just to make cutoff in integral $\int d \omega ...$ at $\omega \sim E$. This gave me following answer
\begin{equation}
      K(\Delta t,x'|x) \approx \frac{m^2}{\pi p_E(x)p_{E'}(x')} \frac{\sin E (T_E(x'|x) - \Delta t)}{T_E(x'|x) - \Delta t} \qquad \delta T \sim 1/E
\end{equation}
However this answer is wrong. I was told that integral $\int d \omega$ conveges at $\omega \ll E$. I don't understand where to make cutoff or such approach is simply wrong and maybe more terms of $\omega$ are needed in expansion.
